# writing sql script base on conceptual schema

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these following requirements

An employer MAY log in to a system with their username and password and create a job opportunity.
An applicant MAY log in to a system with their username and password to view the job opportunity.

- an `employer` has attributes of `employer_id,name,role`
- an `applicant` has attributes of `applicant_id,DOB,Name`
- an `jobOpportunity` has a attributes of `JobId,Title,Description`

This is the diagram I came up with.

[image: ERD]

Transforming the diagram to sql script:

http://pastebin.com/wUnU5NMT

I am not really sure I am writing the script and drawing the diagram correctly according to the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keying on the Login table doesn't look correct, i.e.:

```
 CREATE TABLE Login(
         (employer_id,applicant_id) INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
         -- Username + password OK
         FOREIGN KEY(applicant_id) REFERENCES Applicant(applicant_id));
         FOREIGN KEY(employer_id) REFERENCES Employer(employer_id));
```

Since a login will either be an employer or an applicant, a composite key on both of these makes no sense.

Rather create a surrogate key for the login (e.g. just `LoginID INT`)
It seems like the requirement is pushing you toward an inheritance model between login, employer and applicant. If you do this, the foreign keys will then be switched so that `employer` and `applicant` both FK to login.LoginID. You can either create new surrogate primary keys for employer and login, or use the inherited key from login as the primary key for these tables. (i.e. a column can be both a primary key, and a foreign key at the same time.) Here's how I would do this:

```
 CREATE TABLE Login(
     (LoginID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL);

 CREATE TABLE Employer(
     LoginID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     ROLE VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(LoginID) REFERENCES Login(LoginID));

 CREATE TABLE Applicant(
     LoginID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     DOB VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(LoginID) REFERENCES Login(LoginID));

CREATE TABLE Job(
     (jobId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     ListedByEmployerId INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(ListedByEmployerId) REFERENCES Employer(LoginID));
```

<del>This model doesn't however restrict jobs to be listed by employers only - this would need to be enforced in the application, or with a database rule, trigger etc.</del> Foreign key to `Employer(LoginID)` of course addresses this.

The requirement doesn't mention anything about allowing an applicant to APPLY for a job, so this isn't modelled.

But if they do, you'll need to allow many applicants to apply for a single job - i.e. a Many:Many junction table.

Comment: Note a small but crucial update - you can restrict jobs to being listed by employers by changing the foreign key to `employer(loginid)`.

Comment: sorry I have a question, when you say "You can either create new surrogate primary keys for employer and login" you mean that I can create a employerID in Employer table? so do I have to put employerID as FK in Login table?

Comment: No. I mean you can either create new PRIMARY KEYs Employer.EmployerID and Applicant.ApplicantID on these tables, but since you already have an inheritance relationship, Login.LoginID will suffice as a PRIMARY KEY for both of these tables (subclasses).

Answer (score 0):

In the above schema design, there is no relation between jobs for both the employer and applicant.

If you want to see what are the jobs the employer created or the jobs the applicant applied.

So I would suggest to you to add job id as foreign key to both the employer and applicant table.

Comment: what about the login table? just leave it alone?

Comment: I think the login table is common for both the employer and applicant.And the use of Login table is to have the number of users registered for your application. So you can have id column as key to store both employer and applicant id in common. And also make sure that ur online program take care only the users present in login table has access to create job and apply to job. That's enough...